# Read many files then distinct of column merge in one in R

Tags: r, merge

I have multiple files in folder `file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt`,I want to read them then remove the same rows and merge into one.

```
df1 <- read.delim("/home/D/file1.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " ", quote = "")
df2 <- read.delim("/home/D/file2.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " ", quote = "")
df3 <- read.delim("/home/D/file3.txt", header = FALSE, sep = " ", quote = "")
```

After read data one by one will like:

```
> df1

    No Value
1    A    30
2    B    65
3    C    50
4  A01    72
5  A02     8
6  A03    13

> df2
   No Value
1   A    60
2   B    71
3   C    60
4 A04    43
5 A05     6
6 A06     8

> df3
   No Value
1   A    50
2   B    63
3   C     8
4 A07    47
5 A08     3
6 A09    78
```

Every datatable have the same row of `No: A,B,C`,I want to remove them then merge into one file more efficiency.Desired Output will like:

```
       No Value
1    A    30
2    B    65
3    C    50
4  A01    72
5  A02     8
6  A03    13
7  A04    43
8  A05     6
9  A06     8
10 A07    47
11 A08     3
12 A09    78
```

Any tips is helpful.Thank you.

Comment: what happens to `A,B, C` from df2, df3, etc??

Comment: One way to do this with 'more efficiency' would be to use awk, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"} NR==FNR{$1=$1; print} NR > FNR && FNR > 4 {$1=$1; print}' file*.txt` - would that be an option?

Comment: @jared_mamrot, hi, Thank you. Actually I need to merge another table to get some column in the real data. I prefer using R to merge more the at bash.

Comment: @Onyambu, Hi, I only want to keep df1 ```A,B,C```

Comment: in that case put everything except df1, in a list, remove the first 3 lines and bind all these together with df1

Answer (score 2):

This is a `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% bind_rows(df2, df3) %>% 
  distinct(No, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

```
    No Value
1    A    30
2    B    65
3    C    50
4  A01    72
5  A02     8
6  A03    13
7  A04    43
8  A05     6
9  A06     8
10 A07    47
11 A08     3
12 A09    78
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically the same approach as @Zhiqiang Wang (+1), but with all the text files read into R at once:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(fs)

df <- read_delim(dir_ls(glob = "file*.txt"))

df %>%
  distinct(No, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 2
#>    No    Value
#>    <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 A        30
#>  2 B        65
#>  3 C        50
#>  4 A01      72
#>  5 A02       8
#>  6 A03      13
#>  7 A04      43
#>  8 A05       6
#>  9 A06       8
#> 10 A07      47
#> 11 A08       3
#> 12 A09      78
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>